# Agile Development on Rails: Can someone explain this syntax? image_url: fred.gif)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Newbie question here:

In this test:

```
test "product is not valid without a unique title -il8n" do
      product = Product.new(title: products(:ruby).title),
      description: "yyy",
      price: 1,
      image_url: "fred.gif")
    end
```

Why is there a ")" (closing parenthesis) after "fred.gif"?  There is no opening parenthesis so I do not understand the logic around it.  Can't find any reference on why either.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an error to me, it's not valid syntax:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
$ ruby -c /tmp/test.rb
/tmp/test.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
      description: "yyy",
                  ^
/tmp/test.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
/tmp/test.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
```

I'd guess the line

```
product = Product.new(title: products(:ruby).title),
```

should read

```
product = Product.new(title: products(:ruby).title,
```

so reformatted, the test would look like this:

```
test "product is not valid without a unique title -il8n" do
  product = Product.new(
    title: products(:ruby).title,
    description: "yyy",
    price: 1,
    image_url: "fred.gif"
  )
end
```

(though the test description does not match the behaviour ;-))

Comment: Thank you! You are right.  It is an error in the book (4th ed, P2.0).  It was really frustrating because it is the last exercise in the chapter and afterwards it challenges to create a new validation test.  Suddenly, I find myself with that tLABEL error, and I thought it was something I added...